# How to resolve Xtext variables' names and keywords statically?

Tags: parsing, assembly, xtext

I have a grammar describing an assembler dialect. In code section programmer can refer to registers from a certain list and to defined variables. Also I have a rule matching both [reg0++413] and [myVariable++413]:

```
BinaryBiasInsideFetchOperation:
    '[' 
    v = (Register|[IntegerVariableDeclaration]) ( gbo = GetBiasOperation val = (Register|IntValue|HexValue) )?
    ']'
;
```

But when I try to compile it, Xtext throws a warning:

```
Decision can match input such as "'[' '++' 'reg0' ']'" using multiple alternatives: 2, 3. As a result, alternative(s) 3 were disabled for that input
```

Spliting the rules I've noticed, that

```
BinaryBiasInsideFetchOperation:
    '[' 
        v = Register ( gbo = GetBiasOperation val = (Register|IntValue|HexValue) )?
    ']'
;

BinaryBiasInsideFetchOperation:
    '[' 
    v = [IntegerVariableDeclaration] ( gbo = GetBiasOperation val = (Register|IntValue|HexValue) )?
    ']'
;
```

work well *separately*, but not at the *same time*. When I try to compile both of them, XText writes a number of errors saying that registers from list could be processed ambiguously. So:

1) Am I right, that part of rule v = (Register|[IntegerVariableDeclaration]) matches any IntegerVariable name *including empty*, but rule v = [IntegerVariableDeclaration] matches only nonempty names?

2) Is it correct that when I try to compile separate rules together Xtext thinks that [IntegerVariableDeclaration] can concur with Register?

3) How to resolve this ambiguity?

**edit: definitors**

```
Register: 
    areg = ('reg0' | 'reg1' | 'reg2' | 'reg3' | 'reg4' | 'reg5' | 'reg6' | 'reg7' )
;

IntegerVariableDeclaration:
    section = SectionServiceWord? name=ID ':' type = IntegerType ('[' size = IntValue ']')? ( value = IntegerVariableDefinition )? ';'
;
```

ID is a standart terminal which parses a single word, a.k.a identifier

Comment: Can you show us the definition for Register, IntegerVariableDeclaration and ID rules please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, (Register|[IntegerVariableDeclaration]) can't match Empty. Actually, [IntegerVariableDeclaration] is the same than [IntegerVariableDeclaration|ID], it is matching ID rule.
2. Yes, i think you can't split your rules.
3. I can't reproduce your problem (i need full grammar), but, in order to solve your problem you should look at this [article](http://blog.dietmar-stoll.de/2011/08/xtext-grammar-visualization.html) about xtext grammar debugging:

   - Compile grammar in debug mode by adding the following line into your workflow.mwe2
     `fragment = org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.DebugAntlrGeneratorFragment {}`
   - Open generated antrl debug grammar with AntlrWorks and check the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Fabien's answer, I'd like to add that an omnimatching rule like

```
AnyId:
    name = ID
;
```

instead of

```
 (Register|[IntegerVariableDeclaration])
```

solves the problem. One need to dynamically check if AnyId.name is a Regiser, Variable or something else like Constant.